# Set arithmetic with SharePoint groups

Tags: groups, audience-targeting

Is it possible to perform set arithmetic on sharepoint groups?

An example situation is audiencing.

I want the web part to display to all in group A who do not also belong to group B. And on that page, another web part is to be displayed to group B.

I figure this isnt possible as I cant find a source on it, but I thought id ask people who no doubt have more experience with this than I do.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do this using custom code solution. Is that an option to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems even with complex programming (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms578007.aspx) does not allow you to create the rule because with membership, the only operator I know of is "Member of". See if following helps:

Create three group names and put people in right groups:

> Coders (Set A)
>
> Managers (Set B)
>
> Managers who can write code (Intersection of Set A and Set B)

**Audience 1 (Rules below):**

> user belong to Coders

**Audience 2 [ Rules below]**

> User belong to Managers
>
> Or [in UI this corresponds to Satisfy any of the rules]
>
> Users belong to Managers who can write code

Target WebPart 1 to Audience 1 and WebPart 2 to Audience 2

Comment: I figured this might have to be the way to go, at least out of the box.
I was just hoping for some way of doing group arithmetic.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. This isn't available OOTB but [Waldek has just released a post on Negated Audiences](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/content-targeting-mavention-negated-audiences/)

Comment: Ill check it out. Might have to wait until we finish our upgrade.